# How to write out/convert YYYY-MM-DD to "Month, DD, YYYY" in SQL

Tags: sql, azure, date, sql-date-functions, sql-convert

I'm trying to convert some dates I have that written as `2004-01-05` into `January 1, 2004`.

I can't use `DATEFORMAT()` because it's not a supported built in function in my database. I'm using the up-to-date version of Azure for my database. If I try to use `DATE_FORMAT()`, I get the error:

> date_format is not a recognized built-in function name

I've already done

`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), start`*`date, 107)`*
`FROM` `trial_program`

But I only get "Jan 01, 2004", which is close but not what I want.

How do I write out a whole date as `January 1, 2004` from `2004-01-05`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a date in a `date` or `datetime` then `FORMAT` will format dates for you.

For example:

```
select format(getdate(),'MMMM dd, yyyy')` -- June 22, 2023
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5f342/477

Reference:

[FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

[Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    DATENAME(month, startdate), 
    ' ', 
    CAST(DAY(startdate) AS VARCHAR(2)), 
    ', ', 
    CAST(YEAR(startdate) AS VARCHAR(4))
)
FROM trial_program;
```